# Do attacks by hallucinations trigger an "our forces are under attack" message?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

Basically, I want to know if I can effectively fake some harassment with a force made entirely of hallucinations.

For example, I could fake harassment of one base to draw forces away from the base I actually want to attack.  But I want to make sure that to the opponent, it appears to be a normal attack (except that they take no damage, of course).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they will appear as normal attacks with that warning and everything, but it will be very obvious that they're not doing any damage so I don't think an all-hallucination army would be very effective use of sentry's energy.

If you mix real units in, then it's much harder to tell if they are hallucinations or not.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm sure you're right about mixing in real units, but I just wanted to make sure I knew this little detail. :-)

Comment: A good example would be HuK vs Idra in the recent MLG Dallas. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40ccy9kljvI If you want to watch something funny, watch the start of game 3

Comment: lol, that was awesome! <3 HuK

Comment: IdrA's extreme confidence makes it even more easy and entertaining to toy with. Go HuK!